# how to cache only the content page

Tags: asp.net, webforms, outputcache

I've got a master page with a content page loaded on to it, the content page is cached

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="360" VaryByParam="none"  %>
```

in the master page iv'e got a login control above the content ,
now if i attempt to use the control nothing happens since the content and the master binned to it are cached so the Response is redirect .

1. How could i cache only the content ?
2. Or alternately how can i make it so the login event refreshes the
   cached content page?

OK :  Adding my attempts to resolve the situation

(1) iv'e declared an OutputCache directive in the User Control  itself 
    the problem now is that it wasn't recognized (it's null)  when i redirect to other pages 
    so i added the shared attribute to its directive

```
 <%@ OutputCache Duration="360" VaryByParam="none" Shared="true" %>
```

but it's still null when redirecting to different pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a wild idea which comes to my mind first is to put that dynamic content in a separate page and then reference it as `<iframe>` on your master page.

It will cache all of the things but won't cache the content of the iframe.

Also have a look at below document :

**Caching Portions of an ASP.NET Page**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h30h475z.aspx

Comment: i never used iframes 
ill try that out 
thanks for the quick replay .. 
ill V and + you soon after i try

Comment: kk- though i did like the  iframe idea
but could i place user controls in the i-frame 
or do i have to link aspx pages as there src 
attribute 
?

Comment: @eranotzer you cannot render **.ascx** files directly unless you make special configurations. You need to place them inside an **.aspx** page (I am talking here assuming that you have default configurations)

Comment: probably since i didn't configure any thing . 
that kinda changes my architecture , ill try it out
(you probably guessed by now that i'm new at this)
i appreciate your help and patience.